in python how can I annotate the type of Literal type?
I basically want to have a argument that accept the literal object as input
from typing import Literal, TypeVar, get_args
MyLiteral=Literal["a", "b"]
def func1(
        cls_literal # how to annotate here?
    ):
    print(get_args(cls_literal))

func1(cls_literal=MyLiteral)

Type[Literal] or Literal will not work at all.

get_args is annotated with Any, and you're out of luck here, unfortunately. There's nothing more precise than Any, AFAIC.

Why would you ever want to pass MyLiteral into a function? It would make sense to pass "a" or "b" (because that's what MyLiteral is supposed to indicate), but passing the MyLiteral object itself doesn't seem useful. Maybe you could try and provide some context for why you need to do this?

Literal['a', 'b'] returns a value of type typing._LiteralGenericAlias.
>>> type(Literal['a', 'b'])
<class 'typing._LiteralGenericAlias'>

As the leading _ indicates that this is an implementation detail of the typing module, not a public member, it's questionable whether you should use Literal in this fashion.

Correct at runtime, but such underscore aliases aren't defined in typeshed, so typecheckers won't understand that.

You would annotate as such
from typing import Literal, TypeVar, get_args
MyLiteral = Literal["a", "b"]
def func1(cls_literal: MyLiteral):
    print(get_args(cls_literal))

func1(cls_literal='a')

Alternatively, if there is a particular value you would like to use for the literal, you can use the following annotation
def func1(cls_literal: MyLiteral["a"]):
    print(get_args(cls_literal))

func1(cls_literal='a')

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal

Did you read the question before posting this answer?

the function is meant to be called with func1(cls_literal=MyLiteral), so MyLiteral is incorrect for that annotation.
